# jquery set a form input to textarea value

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a html page form like:

@Model.strPayload

On the button that submits i have

$('#TestForm input[name="assignment"]').val($('textarea#payload').val());

but on post my value remains ""

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please provide us with html snippet?

Comment: $('#TestForm input[name="assignment"]').val($('textarea#payload').val());

Comment: in form<input name="assignment" value="" />

Comment: <textarea name="payload" rows="10" cols="100">@Model.strPayload</textarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that with `$('textarea#payload')` you are trying to select textarea with id payload, and you are using name payload. Try this instead:

```
$('#TestForm input[name="assignment"]').val($('textarea[name="payload"]').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript works fine when fiddled http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/NyYyn/.

Maybe you have a problem with your HTML?

Or maybe the form is submitting before the value is getting replaced?